# jQuery ASP.NET MVC - $.post() to a different URL path in different environments

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Consider the need to  `$.post()` to a slightly different URL structure in the Visual Studio Dev environment vs. deployed IIS Production or Test environment.

When deployed to the Test server, the app is running under a Virtual Directory in IIS. The URL will be something like:

**Deployed**

URL: `http://myServer/myApplication/Area/Controller/Action`

Using jQuery's `.post()`, I need to supply the string:

```
 $.post( "/myApplication/myArea/myController/myMethod"
```

**Development**

When in the Visual Studio environment

Cassini URL is: `http://localhost:123/Area/Controller/Action`

Using jQuery's `.post()`, I need to supply the string:

```
 $.post( "/myArea/myController/myMethod"
```

**Question:**
How can I make both these use the same line of code, regardless of their deployed environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I've done this is by generating the url from the `RouteUrl` method like so:

```
var url = "<%= Url.RouteUrl(new { area="myArea", controller = "controller", action = "actionmethod" }) %>";
$.post(url ...
```

As long as your routes are set up correctly, this will generate the appropriate Url.

**Edit:** Now works with areas without modification.

Answer (score 1):

Another (simpler?) implementation would be to setup a js variable of your application root:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    var globalAppPath = '<%= Request.ApplicationPath %>';
</script>
```

Then you can just append it to the beginning of any url request.

```
$.post( globalAppPath + "/myArea/myController/myMethod"
```

It'll work no matter where you put your web app.